# Accessing Matplotlib Text Object Label Text

Tags: python, matplotlib

Attempting to access the length of a matplotlib axis label with this code:

```
    for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[1::2]:
        print(len(label))
```

However I am getting an error that the object does not have a length attribute. `print(label[2])` also errors out with a similar error.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Matplotlib's text objects can't be accessed through standard indexing - what you're looking for is the `get_text()` attribute found in the [text object documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html). E.g.

```
for label in ax.xaxis.get_tick_labels()[1::2]:
    print(len(label.get_text()))
```

Comment: Does anyone know why the `maplotlib` text objects use a '-' that can't convert to a number?

```
In [66]: secax.get_yticklabels()[0].get_text()
Out[66]: '−2.5'
In [67]: type(a.get_text())
Out[67]: str
In [68]: type(a.get_text()), a
Out[68]: (str, Text(1, -2.5, '−2.5'))

In [69]: float(a.get_text())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-d347a578a778> in <module>
----> 1 float(a.get_text())

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '−2.5'
```

Comment: @tsherwen For whatever reason, the ```'−'``` used by matplotlib is a different minus character (unicode 8722) compared to the regular ```'-'``` (unicode 45).

If you do ```float(a.replace('−', '-').get_text())```, that should work

Answer (score 11):

The `label`s you are iterating over from `get_ticklabels()` are [`matplotlib.text.Text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) objects. To access the actual text in that object, you can use [`get_text()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.get_text).

So, something like this should work:

```
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[1::2]:
    print(len(label.get_text()))
```

Note that this length may include special characters (e.g. latex `$` mathmode delimiters) as it is the length of the raw text string